# making bootstrap nav bar dynamic with php

Tags: php, html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a website in bootstrap, and now I'm trying to make it more dynamic. The course I'm following to do this is not using a bootstrap. Is this something really obvious that I'm missing? Please can you have a look over my code?

(I don't want to overload this post with code so only showing nav.php and array.php) I have included the nav.php to the header within the `<nav></nav>` and the array.php at the very top.

Any help would be really appreciated -  I am just starting out on my journey so please be gentle talk to me like I don't know a lot because this is true I don't! :-)

```
//nav.php which I took out of the header
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Harrisons      Hair &amp; Beauty</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
<ul class="navbar-nav">

    <?php 

        foreach($navItems as $item){
            echo "<li class=\"nav-item\">
                  <a class=\"nav-link\"  href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a>
                  </li>";
        }

    ?>

</ul>
</div>


// array.php
<?php

    $navItems = [
        [
        slug => "index.php"
        title => "Home"
    ],
        [
        slug => "about.php",
        title => "About"
    ],
        [
         slug => "gallery.php",
         title => "Gallery"

    ],
        [
        slug => "other.php",
        title => "Other Services"
    ],
        [
        slug => "contact.php",
        title => "Find Us"
    ],
        [
        slug => "test.php",
        title => "Test Page"
    ]
];
?>
```

Comment: What do you mean with dynamic. Dynamic showing some different items if there is a user logged in or some anmimations in the browser.

Comment: Replace `echo "<li class=\"nav-item\"><a class=\"nav-link\"  href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a></li>";` With `echo '<li class="nav-item">
 <a class="nav-link"  href="'.$item["slug"].'">'.$item["title"].'</a>
</li>';`

Comment: Hi Sweting. I was hoping to achieve going from one page to another without reloading pages all the time and if I wanted to add another menu item for example, I was hoping to just add this to the array and it would appear?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your array is malformed. Wrap keys in " " and add a comma behind "index.php". Also change `foreach($navItems as $item){` to `foreach($navItems as $key => $item){` to retrieve the nested array values (nav-items).

With these adjustments your code works just fine.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <!-- required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- Libraries - jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap.js -->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
<?php
$navItems = [
    [   // keys (i.e. slug and title) need surrounding ""
        "slug" => "index.php", // missing comma
        "title" => "Home"
    ],
    [
        "slug" => "about.php",
        "title" => "About"
    ],
    [
        "slug" => "gallery.php",
        "title" => "Gallery"

    ],
    [
        "slug" => "other.php",
        "title" => "Other Services"
    ],
    [
        "slug" => "contact.php",
        "title" => "Find Us"
    ],
    [
        "slug" => "test.php",
        "title" => "Test Page"
    ]
];
?>

<!-- nav.php which I took out of the header -->
<a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Harrisons      Hair &amp; Beauty</a>
<button style = "color: #0000FF !important; border: 1px solid blue !important;" class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNav" aria-controls="navbarNav" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    toggle menu<span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-end" id="navbarNav">
    <ul class="navbar-nav">

        <?php

        foreach($navItems as $key => $item){

            echo "<li class=\"nav-item\" style='color: #FFFFFF !important;'>
                  <a class=\"nav-link\"  href=\"$item[slug]\">$item[title]</a>
                  </li>";
        }

        ?>

    </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Lovelace, Thank you so much for spotting that. Strange thing is its still not working?

Comment: Have posted working code, have a look, hope it helps. Note: your original `foreach($navItems as $item){` changed to `foreach($navItems as $key => $item){` to retrieve the navitems in your nested array.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help.. Really appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

For concatenating the strings in your echo statements you can either use

- `echo "..." . $item['slug'] . "..."` 
  or
- `echo "... {$item['slug']} ..."`.

Also make sure the declaration of your `$navItems` array is before the `echo` output statement.

Good luck.